# Is it possible to integrate Log4net and Splunk without a Forwarder?

Tags: umbraco, log4net, splunk

I'm trying to send Umbraco logs into Splunk, and I'm investigating a way to do this without using a forwarder. We are hosting Umbraco in Azure.

I'm looking into Log4net [RemoteAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html#RemotingAppender), but it doesn't seem to be a way to authenticate against Splunk.

Is there an other option?

I found this options, but all of them seem to need installing some library or writing code, and I'm looking for an option that only needs changing the config file "log4net.config":

- http://dev.splunk.com/view/splunk-loglib-dotnet/SP-CAAAEX4
- https://github.com/AlanBarber/log4net.Appender.Splunk

And this answer suggest using a forwarder: https://answers.splunk.com/answers/94364/plugin-support-for-log4net.html

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There won't be any other ways. `Log4net` should have to provide an integrated approach like other logging technics `serilog`, `Nlog` etc.

Comment: you can add an event collector  like this in web config -


<appender name="abc">
   <ServerUrl>http_url_splunk</ServerUrl>
   <Token>guid_token</Token>
   <RetriesOnError>10</RetriesOnError>
   <BatchIntevalMs>100</BatchIntevalMs>
   <BatchSizeCount>10</BatchSizeCount>
   <SendMode>Parallel</SendMode>
   <IgnoreCertificateErrors>True</IgnoreCertificateErrors>
   <threshold value="INFO" />

   <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger  - %message%newline" />
   </layout>
  </appender>